# How to measure the parse time?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I have a flex/bison parser that reads a text file, parses it and the "start" rule in my ".y" file uses `printf` to output the results. I want to measure the parse time (not the time to read in the text file and not the time to output the results). I want to run the parse 100 times and calculate the average parse time. How do I do that? I tried the below code but what I found happening (I think) is the parser reads the input file, parses it, outputs the results, and then gives 99 "error: syntax error" messages. Eek! What is the correct way to do this, please?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timeval begin, end;
    
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    
    // Start measuring time
    gettimeofday(&begin, 0);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
        yyparse();
    
    // Stop measuring time and calculate the elapsed time
    gettimeofday(&end, 0);
    long seconds = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
    long microseconds = end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec;
    double elapsed = seconds + microseconds*1e-6;
    printf("Total time for 100 parses: %.6f seconds.\n", elapsed);
    printf("Time per parse: %.6f seconds.\n", elapsed/100);
    
    fclose(yyin);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're concerned about parse time, don't be. I measured a bare-bones YACC-generated Cobol parser, no actions, at 50,000 lines per minute, mostly I/O ... in 1987 on a 4MHz processor. At today's processor speeds that would be maybe 30,000 lines per *second.* And you can read *millions* of lines per second these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Note:* This answer mostly addresses the question of how to read the same input more than once. I added a small note about benchmarking at the end.)

In a bison-generated parser, the parser asks the lexical scanner for each token as it needs it, and the lexical scanner reads the input in buffers in order to satisfy the requests. So it's not really possible to separate parsing time from reading time; reading is interleaved with parsing. (All input is done by the lexical scanner. Bison-generated parsers do not require `stdio.h` for parsing at all, although it's usually included in order to be able print error messages and debugging information.)

As you might expect from this model, when you provide a `FILE*` to the lexical scanner by assigning it to `yyin`, the file is consumed up to the point at which parsing terminates, either by reading up to the end of the file or by encountering a syntax error. In order to parse the entire input a second time, you would need to rewind the file yourself; flex-generated scanners never attempt to do that.

It is not always possible to rewind files; that only works if the file is an ordinary disk file. Pipes, sockets, terminals and other such objects --all of which are "files" in the terms of the C standard library-- can only be read once. So code which depends on rereading its input should be prepared for the possibility of failure, perhaps by copying to a temporary file.

One possible solution would be to read the entire file into memory yourself, and then provide it to the flex-generated scanner using `yy_scan_bytes`. Note that flex-generated scanners do not preserve the contents of their input buffer; consequently, `yy_scan_bytes` makes a dynamically-allocated copy of the data you give it, and you must make sure that you free this copy by deleting the buffer state after the parse is complete.

An even more drastic solution, which would eliminate the time used to tokenise the input as well, would be to create an array of tokens by calling `yylex` repeatedly until it returns an EOF indication (return value ≤0). You could then feed this array into using a tokeniser which simply successively returns array values. (Since you can't use `yylex` for both names, you'd have to arrange for one of them to have a different name. See `YY_DECL` for a simple way to rename the scanner generated by flex.)

If you do this, watch out for dynamically-allocated token semantic values; if your scanner makes allocates these values and your parser frees them (which is a common architecture) then you won't be able to simply rerun the token sequence, since all the semantic values will have been freed. Instead, your token wrapper will have to make new copies of all dynamically-allocated values before returning the token to the parser.

---

#### On benchmarking parsers:

For most purposes, the detailed time measurement referred to in this question is not going to prove very useful. If the final goal is to compare two different parsing strategies (different grammars, or different ways to split the work between parser and scanner), then there is no particular need to remove the I/O cost; unless the input file is very large, buffering of the input file in your OS's kernel will save most of the I/O cost, so just discarding the benchmarks during the first few warm-up iterations will provide a reasonably accurate measure. In any case, that's a more realistic metric than attempting to eliminate I/O altogether.

Microbenchmarks of parsers are pretty common, mostly as attempts to compare different parser generators, but as you might imagine they are not particular helpful, since the benchmarkers tend to either have a personal bias (that is, they want to demonstrate the superiority of their own product) or to not have a detailed knowledge of optimising different parsing frameworks, or both. Because the speed of parsing in practical applications is often largely dependent on cache effects and on the speed of the dynamic memory allocator being used, there might not be much correlation with the results of microbenchmarks in which these externalities are minimised. Finally, if it is difficult to see the comparative cost of two different parsing strategies within the context in which the parser is deployed, that's probably prima facie evidence that it doesn't make much difference in practice and that optimisation efforts should be directed elsewhere.

As suggested by [Kaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68867363/1566221), profiling the parser may well be a better strategy, depending on what your data collection needs really are.

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you (again) @rici

Answer (score 1):

Time the `yyparse` function, and also time the `yylex` function. Subtract the time spent in `yylex` from the time spent in `yyparse`.

Normally, this kind of thing is done with profiling tools. A profiling tool will tell you directly how much time was spent in `yyparse`, and break that down by how much was in `yyparse` itself versus its children.

It sounds as if your investigation is headed in the direction of a level of detail that calls for profiling.